# How to override URL suffix for Hystrix metrics stream endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, dropwizard, metrics, microservices

In our setup we have lots of Dropwizard services which are streaming their metrics to a Hystrix dashboard.

We are writing a new service in Spring Boot and would like the metrics stream to be on the same URL as the Dropwizard one, but I can't find out how to override the stream servlet's URL pattern.

I'm sure this is configurable somehow, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had to register a custom bean to override the hard coded value like this in the application class:

```
@Bean
public CustomHystrixStreamEndpoint customHystrixStreamEndpoint() {
    return new CustomHystrixStreamEndpoint();
}
```

and the create the custom wrapper class like this:

```
    public class CustomHystrixStreamEndpoint extends ServletWrappingEndpoint {

        public CustomHystrixStreamEndpoint() {
            super(HystrixMetricsStreamServlet.class, "customHystrixStream",
                  "/tenacity/hystrix.stream",
                  false, true);
        }
    }
```

and then turn off the default one like this in the config file:

```
hystrix.stream.endpoint.enabled: false
```

FYI the default wrapper class is called HystrixStreamEndpoint